# get list of nodes using CloudifyClient

Tags: cloudify

I am trying to get a list of Tosca nodes within my blueprint but it returns all the nodes in the whole cloudify (includes nodes from other blueprints)

`nodes = client.nodes.list(_include=['id','type','properties'])`

I expect to get a list of nodes in a specific blueprint.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain node templates for a blueprint:

```
blueprint = client.blueprints.get(blueprint_id, _include=['plan'])
nodes = blueprint.plan['nodes']
```

`nodes` will be a list of dictionaries, each one represents a node template.